# custome ios app cannot find my nrf beacons

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon, uuid, locationmanager

I have some beacons with this uuid:

0112233445566778899aabbccddeeff0
and major = 1 but their minor are different.

this is a part of firmware code which shows these numbers:

```
#define APP_MAJOR_VALUE                 0x01, 0x02                        #define APP_MINOR_VALUE                 0x03, 0x04                        
#define APP_BEACON_UUID                 0x01, 0x12, 0x23, 0x34, \
                                        0x45, 0x56, 0x67, 0x78, \
                                        0x89, 0x9a, 0xab, 0xbc, \
                                        0xcd, 0xde, 0xef, 0xf0  
    static uint8_t m_beacon_info[APP_BEACON_INFO_LENGTH] =                 
{
    APP_DEVICE_TYPE,                             
    APP_ADV_DATA_LENGTH,
    APP_BEACON_UUID,     
    APP_MAJOR_VALUE,    
    APP_MINOR_VALUE,    
    APP_MEASURED_RSSI                            
};
```

and this is my swift code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import CoreBluetooth

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    var managerBLE: CBCentralManager?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        managerBLE = CBCentralManager(delegate: nil, queue: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: true])

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }

        startScanning()
    }

    func startScanning() {
        let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: "your UUID")!, major: 1, identifier: "MyBeacon")
        locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion)
    }



    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        if beacons.count > 0 {            
            for beacon in beacons {
                updateDistance(beacon.proximity)
                if beacon.proximity == .near {
                    // run your code
                }else if beacon.proximity == .far {
                    // run your code
                }
            }
        } 
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

but when i instaall my app on my iphone basically nothing happens. I have no idea what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to be debugged. Unfortunately it's tough for us to do because we don't have beacon. Try printing to the logs when ever you are able to connect to a beacon. It's a good starting place for debugging.

Make sure your beacon's have battery and that they are in range.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

- This line: `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse` should be `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != .authorizedWhenInUse`
- You need to place your UUID including dashes in place of the string "your UUID" in this line `CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: "your UUID")!,`
- There is no need to use `CBCentralManager` at all.

**EDIT**: You should also try an off-the-shelf beacon detector app like [Locate](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8) (entering your UUID with dashes to configure it to detect your beacon) and verify it sees it.  If it does not see, it, it may be an issue with your hardware beacon, or perhaps the UUID is not what you think it is.

Comment: I have done what you asked me but nothing happened. I add an answer myself, to explain more details. would you please check that and lemme know what you think?

Answer (score 0):

> SWIFT 3:

- First of all you should add in the .Plist file add the key/string `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`with appropriate string
- In your Object add the `CLLocationManagerDelegate`
- Add the  `CLLocationManagerDelegate` delegate methods in this example i will just add the didRangeBeacons method

> ```
> func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons
> beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
>            print(beacons)   }
> ```

- Create and initialise the locationManager

  `let locationManager : CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()`
- Create the `CLBeaconRegion`

  ```
  let beaconRegion : CLBeaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(
      proximityUUID: NSUUID.init(uuidString:"****-****-****-****-******") as! UUID,
      identifier: "my beacon")
  ```
- Add the delegate to your Object `locationManager.delegate = self`
- Request the Location authorization from the user with

> locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

Now let's start the Range

```
  locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion)
```

This will automatically call the delegate method

```
   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        print(beacons)

    }
```